# Is it possible to make your own DIY cookie mix?

Tags: cookies

Is it possible to create DIY mixes for cookies? I make chocolate chip cookies often enough to want to streamline the process. My idea is to create my own combine the dry ingredients, storing them in a box/tupperware of some kind, and then combining it with the wet ingredients when its time to bake.

My hypothesis is that it -should- be possible with pretty much any cookie recipe, but I thought it best to ask.

Comment: You can, but it saves pretty much no time at all. Freezing the portioned dough is more effective as a timesaver if you make a lot of dough but only a few cookies at a time.

Comment: Depends on your recipe... if it starts by creaming butter and sugar/s, you can't premix the sugars with the flour.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, freezing cookie dough would be a far better option. If you could post that as an answer I can accept it @Ecnerwal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Freezing the portioned dough is more effective as a timesaver if you make a lot of dough but only a few cookies at a time. And as Catija notes, if you need to cream the butter and sugar a complete dry mix would not be practical.

Comment: What is frozen needs thawing, which can be quite time consuming... unless you freeze ready shaped individual cookie blanks (space consuming) or want to use a saw to shape...

Comment: My prior comment did specifically suggest pre-portioning. Which is not very space consuming at all if you freeze on a sheet (temporary space-intensive) and then bag the frozen cookie blanks.

Comment: Speaking of, do you need to thaw the frozen cookie blanks before baking or can you just toss em in the oven straight from the freezer?

Comment: if you adjust the time slightly, straight from the freezer works. if you don't adjust the time, thaw.